# How to permanently fix destination column maps in SSIS 2014

Tags: ssis, ssis-2014

I have an SSIS 2014 solution in Visual Studio 2015. The solution has multiple configurations. The solution is under source control in Git. The project is set for project deployment.

[image: SSIS 2014 Project]

The issue I'm having is that the column mapping in the destinations keep disappearing every time anybody makes a change and checks it back into Git. The disappearances do not happen in the same areas.

[image: Disappearing Column Maps]

I have tried recreating the project, then the whole solution, but this keeps happening. I even recreated the solution and put it under a different repository in Git. This is the first time in 10+ years of working with SSIS that I've seen something like this.

So far I haven't found anything on the different search engines.

**EDIT:**

The sources are just regular OLE DB sources with T-SQL queries that are typed in the "SQL command text:" box. Nothing fancy.

[image]

The project has one master package with 8 child packages. That child packages are called using the "Execute Package Task." All the child packages are self-contained, so no parameters are being passed from the master package.

**The disappearances do not happen in the same areas**

This means that the destination columns getting unmapped, happen randomly on the data flow in any of the 8 child packages. It's different every time any of us open the packages to check on the package logic. The destinations are just OLE DB destinations. So nothing fancy here either.

[image]

So anytime anybody in the team makes changes in any of the packages, any number of the child packages will unmap columns randomly in their data flows. There's no pattern to this behavior. That's why it's so maddening.

Comment: Where are those missing Input Columns supposed to be coming from? Can you show us more of the package structure? And what do you mean by `The disappearances do not happen in the same areas.`?

Comment: If you have a copy of the package in is correct and unmapped states, please do a side-by-side comparison of the XML between them.  That could provide clues as to why the values are changing.